# How can I get the number of lines of a text file before and after it is changed

Tags: python

I want to get the number of lines in a file before and after it is appended and want to read the lines present only in that range(read only the lines that are appended to the file)
Code explanation.

- open the `sample.log` and read the number of lines in it and store in another file `line_count.txt`
- If the `line_count.txt` does not exist OR its size is 0 that means `sample.log` is being read for the first time(before appending), so open `line_count.txt` and add the count of number of lines of `sample.log` to it.
- If log file is read after appending, read `line_count.txt` and get the previous value stored in it and replace that value with the new line count(no of lines in file after appending)

  This is my code, that I have come up with.

> ```
> prev_lc=0
> lc_now=0
> with open('sample.txt', 'r') as myfile:
>     lc_now=len(myfile.readlines())
> if os.path.exists('line_count.txt') and os.stat('line_count.txt').st_size!=0:
>     cmd="cat line_count.txt"
>     prev_lc=os.system(cmd)
>     with open("line_count.txt", 'w') as myfile1:
>         myfile1.write(str(lc_now))
> else:
>     with open("line_count.txt", 'w') as myfile2:
>         myfile2.write(str(lc_now))
> return [prev_lc, lc_now]
> ```

But my function is not returning me correct values,
For example, if `sample.log` has 5 lines before and after it got appended, it has 10 lines, my code should return [5,10], it is only returning [0,10]

`cat line_count.txt`
`5`

line_count has only 1 value in it --> number of lines of the log file
I feel like I have ended up complicating the whole code, how can I optimise it?

Answer (score 0):

when you re using `os.system(cmd)` it's just execute the command `cat file.txt` and print the content of the file on the console but it returns 0 so `prev_lc` will be always equal to 0 instead of using this command try to open the file and read the first line.
Another thing is when you open a file with `w` mode and write in you remove all file previous content instead use `a` here is a suggestion for the code:

```
prev_lc=0
lc_now=0
with open('sample.txt', 'r') as myfile:
    lc_now=len(myfile.readlines())

with open("line_count.txt", 'r') as myfile1:
        file_lines=myfile1.readlines()
        if file_lines:
          prev_lc=file_lines[-1]
        else:
          prev_lc=0 
with open("line_count.txt","a") as f       
        f.write(str(lc_now)+'\n')

return [prev_lc, lc_now]
```